# Python: ¿Como recorro una lista?

Tags: python

Quiero recorrer una lista en Python para contar la cantidad de integrantes que tiene un equipo (es solo un ejemplo, no estoy haciendo ningún proyecto), pero me aparece este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dir", line 17, in <module>
    for i in range(team1):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Este es el código:

```
print("team1 = " + str(team1));
j = 0;
for i in range(team1): # Aqui esta el error
    j+=1;
print("team1 has " + str(j) + " member(s)");
```

¿Cómo hago para contar correctamente la cantidad de índices que hay en la lista?

Comment: Si quieres iterar en el rango de la lista debes hacer `range(len(team1))`. Ya que `range` espera como argumento un número. Además si quieres saber el número de elementos basta con hacer `len(team1)`

Comment: Gracias, ya funciona! Ponlo como respuesta asi te apruebo :D

Comment: Ando un poco corto de tiempo, puedes ponerlo tu así te voto a favor ^_^

Comment: Okey no hay problema!

Comment: `print("team1 has", len(team1),"member(s)");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a los comentarios (Christian) ya se como hacer que funcione:

Si quieres iterar en el rango de la lista debes hacer `range(len(team1))`. Ya que `range` espera como argumento un número

```
print("team1 = " + str(team1));
j = 0;
for i in range(len(team1)): # Aqui esta el error
    j+=1;
print("team1 has " + str(j) + " member(s)");
```

Pero támbien basta tan solo con poner simplemente `len(team1)` para obtener de forma rápida el número de elementos de una lista :D

Comment: Te puedes ahorrar el bucle. Ya que `len()` te dice cuántos elementos tiene la lista, puedes ir directamente al print final y poner `print("Team has", len(team1), "member(s)")`

Comment: Ah, y `print()` admite varios parámetros separados por comas, por lo que no necesitas usar la concatenación de cadenas `+` (ni el `str()`). `print()` se ocupa de convertir cada uno de los parámetros recibidos en una cadena y de juntarlas toads (separadas por espacios) en una línea en el output.